# How add column in Pandas with using 2 existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

There is my problem .

[image: 1]

Like the question said I try find the largest value . Actually , I didn't understand the question to . That question is my first question so if I not describe my problem and myself sorry .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Answer (score -1):

```
df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['col1'] * row['col2'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you tell that how can I find " the row that corresponds to the largest value." to ?

Comment: Use the idxmax() method to find the index of the row with the maximum value in the new column 'C'

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work . If you can please look at the image which I putted , then write all code

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post